# How to write to trace listeners defined in config file

Tags: c#, wcf, logging, trace

I have WCF service hosted in IIS.
I add section to Web.config for logging exceptions:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Critical, Error">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xmlTrace" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="ErrorLog.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

How can I write handled exceptions to this log?
Something like this:

```
try
{

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Trace.Write(ex,"Error");
}
```

**UPD:** Trace.Listeners does not contains listeners defined in Web.config when I try to use it in WCF request, only DefaultTraceListener that writes to Visual Studio output. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Trace.TraceError()` to write to the trace listeners:

```
try
{

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Trace.TraceError(ex.Message);
}
```

Notice that this will write to all listeners defined in your `web.config` file. Read more on MSDN: [How to: Create and Initialize Trace Listeners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk36c28t.aspx)

Comment: Trace.Listeners does not contains listeners defined in Web.config when I try to use it in WCF request, only DefaultTraceListener that writes to Visual Studio output. Any ideas why?

Comment: @nicolas2008 Note that if your web service is being called through the client using VS Debugger, the application reads the caller's (client's) we.config file, not the service's. Try adding the config section to your startup/client project and see if you can see the listeners now.